# Create a new list in a for loop every time necessary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, greedy

So I am trying to create a new SEPARATE list every time a statement is true in python. Essentially:

```
for i in range(z):
    if X is true:
        create a new list
```

There is no way to know how many lists I need, I can try to estimate as I am doing a greedy type algorithm but I am struggling to figure out how iteratively make new separate lists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop this might help

Comment: Please provide the values of `X` and of `z`.

Comment: `l = []`? Perhaps we could be of more help if you explained what algorithm you were trying to write.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
myList = []
for i in range(z):
  if X is true:
    lis = []        
    #do something with lis
  myList.append(lis)
```

If you post exactly what you want to do after creating a new list, then a more efficient answer can be explained.. Based on the provided information, this is all I could come up with.